# contact form 7 and contact form 7 success page redirect plugin conflicts

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have implemented these two plugins:

- contact form 7, and
- contact form 7 success page redirect.

These plugins been conflicts.

Firstly, the client side validation is not working.

Secondly, on success it is not redirecting to success page.

Comment: You forgot to ask any question. Also, if this is in any way related to PHP or JS, please share the code involved

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to redirect users upon successful message then better approach would be to use javascript hook.

Remove the success page redirect plugin.

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

just go to Additional Settings tab in contact form 7 and paste this without any leading spaces, replace your success page url with the example.com.

Comment: indeed on success ajax throws 302 exeption, and redirect page html

Comment: Have you tried this after removing the success page redirect plugin? @ManS.

Comment: indeed client want to stick with that plugin

Answer (score 0):

To work on client side validation, please put these lines in footer.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=3.5.2'></script>



<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.40.0-2013.08.13'></script>



<script type='text/javascript'>
```

please copy syntax at your own this is cdata .>var _wpcf7 = {"loaderUrl":"/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif","sending":"Sending ..."};
  ]]>

now in your cf7-success-page-redirects.php that is in plugin directory .

change this function

```
function cf7_success_page_form_submitted( $contact_form ) {
$contact_form_id = $contact_form->id();

// Send us to a success page, if there is one
$success_page = get_post_meta( $contact_form_id, '_cf7_success_page_key', true );
if ( !empty($success_page) ) {
    $items = array();
    $items['mailSent'] = true;
    $items['redirectLink'] =get_permalink( $success_page );
    echo wp_json_encode( $items );
    die();
}
```

}

now in your contact form 7 directory of plugin find js folder , and look for script.php and replace this bunch of code.

```
else if (1 == data.mailSent) {
        $responseOutput.addClass('wpcf7-mail-sent-ok');
        $form.addClass('sent');

        if (data.onSentOk) {
            $.each(data.onSentOk, function(i, n) { eval(n) });
        }

        $(data.into).trigger('wpcf7:mailsent');
        $(data.into).trigger('mailsent.wpcf7'); // deprecated
        location.assign(data.redirectLink);



    }
```

i have fixed this on my website for client hope this will help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in **functions.php** (located in themes -> themeName Folder).

Put this in the end of file.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( e ) {
    var str = window.location.href;
    if( str.includes("flp") ){
        window.location.href = "http://www.WebsiteName.com/facebook-thank-you";
    } else if( str.includes("glp") ){
        window.location.href = "http://www.WebsiteName.com/google-thank-you";
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Working Perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to redirect users upon a successful message submission, a more efficient approach would be to use a JavaScript hook.

You can remove the success page redirect plugin and use the following code instead:

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://example.com/';"
```

Simply navigate to the Additional Settings tab in Contact Form 7 and paste this code without any leading spaces. Be sure to replace "example.com" with your desired success page URL.

If you want to learn more about these settings, just check the Contact form 7 official doc [here](https://contactform7.com/additional-settings/#javascript).

However, if you need a non-code solution with more advanced customization like 'redirect & open in a new tab', 'conditional redirect', 'redirect to whatsapp' or 'pass value', then I would suggest trying a contact form 7 addon like this [one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-addons-for-contact-form-7/).